# Prevent solution explorer from going behind intellitrace when debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Every time I start debugging in VS2013, the intellitrace window hides the solution explorer window.  I click back on the solution explorer tab and end debugging.   Then, when I start debugging again, the intellitrace window again hides the solution explorer and I have to click on the solution explorer tab again to bring it up.  How do I stop this behavior and set it so that the solution explorer always is the active tab when I start debugging?  Thanks before hand.

Answer (score 0):

Try grabbing the solution explorer window and sticking it to one of the side panels. This way, you can view both the debug window and the solution explorer at the same time.
[image]

I would say this is a more useful view anyway, otherwise I'd be endlessly tabbing between the two throughout the day

Comment: It is on the right side panel together with the intellitrace window.  But no matter how many times I select solution explorer tab, it still brings up the intellitrace as the active tab when I start a new debug session.

Comment: Then try moving one or the other onto a different tab area so they are both visible at the same time.